# Why are HtmlEncode and HtmlDecode not isomorphic in .NET?

Tags: .net, unicode, html-entities, html-encode

I find this surprising, and rather annoying.

Example:

```
Decode(&rdquo;) => ”
Encode(”)       => ”
```

Relevant classes:

```
.NET 4:   System.Net.WebUtility
.NET 3.5: System.Web.HttpUtility
```

I can understand that a web page can be Unicode, but it my case the output cannot be UTF8.

Is there something (perhaps a HtmlWriter class) that could do this without me having to re-invent the wheel?

**Alternative solution:**

```
string HtmlUnicodeEncode(string input)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (var c in input)
    {
        if (c > 127)
        {
            sb.AppendFormat("&#x{0:X4};", (int)c);
        }
        else
        {
            sb.Append(c);
        }
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: This is not idempotence you are talking about btw. Idempotence is the property `f(f(x)) = f(x)`, which seems to hold for Encode(”).

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Thanks, I seem to have misunderstood the meaning. Can you think of a better term? Perhaps 'reversible'?

Comment: I believe you are expecting the two to be the inverse of each other (and thus they would define an isomorphism!).

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Isomorphic seems perfect :)

Comment: What happens if you try something that isn't a quote character? I am wondering if it doesn't encode it because it doesn't need encoding. Try `<` (`&lt;`)

Comment: @musefan: There is small basic set that does encode, like `<` to `&lt;`. `&lt;` encoded would go to `&amp;lt;` (IIRC)

Comment: I propose a better question: How to HTML-encode all characters except ASCII characters?

Comment: @usr: Good point. Added my naive solution before I saw your comment ;p Took all of 30 seconds to write.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is impossible to produce an isomorphic HTML codec pair. Consider:

```
HtmlDecode("&rdquo;”&#x201D;&#x201d;&#8221;") -> ”””””
```

how do you get back from `”””””` to the original string?

`HtmlEncode` has to pick one encoding for `”`, and it goes for `”` as the shortest, most readable alternative. As long as you've got working Unicode, that's almost certainly the best choice.

If you don't, that's another argument... the advantage of `&rdquo;` is that it's slightly more readable than `&#x201D;`, but it only works in HTML (not XML) and you still have to fall back to character references for all the Unicode characters that don't have built-in entity names, so it's less consistent. For a character-reference encoder, create an [`XmlTextWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162588.aspx) using the ASCII encoding and call [`writeString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextwriter.writestring.aspx) on it.

Comment: +1: Good point :) My problem is that the output HTML cannot be Unicode. Guess I will have to make a database change request to support Unicode. Or manually encode Unicode characters to the hexadecimal escape notation.

Comment: +1 I think this answer should be accepted and the follow up question handled in a new Q&A

Comment: Definitely having native Unicode in your database is the way to go, in order to ensure database functions like `LIKE` text comparisons work appropriately for Unicode strings (and because encoding/decoding on the way in/out of the database is such a mighty pain). If you're on SQL Server it should be simple to get Unicode support by using `NVARCHAR` and `N''` strings.

Comment: Thanks for the `XmlTextWriter` hint, it seems to do what I need :)